# Another what am I? riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Take my first six for a joyride;
>   Take my last five as a number; (edited)
>   My inner workings I cannot confide;
>   But of my hand? - it never slumbers.

What am I?

Comment: Couldn't manage to solve this, so I [wrote my own](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94480/5373) :-P

Comment: I edited the second line for better clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **sleight**

---

> sleigh - for joyride
>  eight - as number
>  inside is lei which may reference Legal Entity Identifier?
>  sleight of hand

---

**Original answer:**

> **cruiserweight**

---

> cruise - for a joyride
>  eight - as a number
>  can't let hands rest when boxing

Comment: Not what I intended, but definitely a viable alternative. Welp, looks like there's at least two good answers out there.

Comment: Your second answer is it! Nicely done! Kudos for finding the intended answer as well as an alternative. Also rot13(Vaare jbexvatf ersreerq gb abg tvivat njnl frpergf jura cresbezvat "fyrvtug bs unaq", ohg gurer ner yvxryl znal vagrecergngvbaf bs gung yvar)

Comment: rot13(V frr, gung'f irel tbbq. V bevtvanyyl vagrecergrq vg nf n uvag sbe gur vasvk. V jnf orgjrra guvaxvat gung vg jnf whfg na rkgen yvar fnlvat gung gurer'f ab uvag sbe gur vasvk be gung gur vasvk unq fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu "abg pbasvqvat".)

Comment: The lack of infix also played into the ambiguity of that line, secondarily, yes. :)