# Going back to a previous way of life

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Going back to a previous way of life:
>   At first I'm really a type of strife,
>   In the middle I once depicted slumber,
>   And in the end I may help number.

**Find the word.**

Comment: Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94474/5373) but the solution is (presumably) different.

Comment: Apparently this is the 2020th [tag:word] puzzle on PSE :-D

Comment: i can't find the "may help number" on the other riddle, and now you ask to find it again?? Evil.

Comment: @SteveV They're both solved now (although completely different meanings of the number line).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going back to a previous way of life:

> feudalist - one perhaps living in medieval Europe

At first I'm really a type of strife,

> feud - a mutually hostile situation.

In the middle I once depicted slumber,

> Salvador **Dali** - painted "Sleep" in 1937

And in the end I may help number.

> list - a way to order or number.

Comment: Well, that didn't last long ... yep, you got it. Out of interest, which bit was the giveaway?

Comment: @Rand - the prefix. I watched a programme called 'Age of the Image' last night, in which the infix was featured, but thought of the full word and had to look-up line 3.